# iPhone locked due to Activation Lock

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-id

We are facing an issue with iPhone due to activation lock.

The device was used by an **ex-employee** of the company.

The email address that was used for this device no longer exists because it looks like '**employeename@company.com**'. So we can't use the forgot password or reset password options.

Is there any solution to use this device?

[image: Activation Lock]

Comment: You need to reset the phone **before** deleting the email identity...

Comment: I can't do anything... I don't have email account or any other option.